# C++ and a string join seperator

Tags: python, c++

I've been working on an open source project working on cleaning up it's database handling. In most places the work has been going well, but in one specific area involving string manipulation for custom queries the code has consistently been ugly.

What we need to do is essentially at run time join a specific component of a query multiple times with a separator.

The way it's currently being done is to set a counter, loop through a specific set checking for a value, and if we have this value we append "(%i, %i)" to the initial query string then set the append state flag and from then on we append ", (%i, %i)" which works, but the code ends up with this weird if then construct within the loop with a flag just because we need that ", " separator after the initial append.

It would be much nicer to have some kind of join system similar to pythons ",".join construct. The only issue is that the strings are not in an array/vector but are found at run time and the strings to append are a constant.

Any suggestions on how to handle this issue?

Comment: Sample code please regarding what is currently being done. Sorry, it just helps me think.

Comment: "The only issue is that the strings are not in an array/vector but are found at run time". And stored in what? If you can put them into _anything_ that can be iterated over (which doesn't have to be an in-memory collection; see `istream_iterator` for a simple example), then you can use something like `boost::algorithm::join` on it, or write your own equivalent pretty easily.

Comment: the string to append is constant (either "(%i, %i) " or ", (%i, %i)" depending on if it's the first to be added or not).

If to append or not is determined at runtime by some value inside an array.

this is why I can't just use some ",".join(iteratble) construct like python has. I don't have a collection of iterables, I have a collection of items and a constant of strings which I may or may not append, and the first must not have the "," preceding and all the rest will.

Comment: dead github link

Answer (score 3):

It may not be the most efficient way but I find my code frequently ends up in this sort of pattern:

```
std::stringstream ss
for( int i = 0; i < numberOfStrings; i++ )
    ss << ( i ? "," : "" ) << GetString(i);
std::string result = ss.str();
```

Comment: That would work, we are trying to avoid the stringstreams we currently have so I would prefer to avoid this type of construct if I could.

That being said, it definitely would work.

Some of the nastier versions of this construct, for example where the first instance to apply may be in the middle of the collection instead of always the first element since it may have to skip most elements or even all elements, will be more difficult! arghh

Comment: OK, then you could make a subclass of `std::string` that has new method `AppendElement( std::string s )`.  Internally, it keeps a counter of the number of elements appended.  It interposes the delimiter when the counter is already non-zero and `AppendElement` is called.

Comment: @AddtheIce  *we are trying to avoid [...] stringstreams* -- for what reason?

Answer (score 0):

What about starting the loop at index 1 instead of 0 ? 
Adapted from your code :

```
char *buf = 0;
MakeAnyLenString(&buf, "(%i, %i)", CharID, TasksEnabled[0]);
TaskQuery += buf;
safe_delete_array(buf);
for(unsigned int i=1; i<TasksEnabled.size(); i++) {
    MakeAnyLenString(&buf, ",(%i, %i)", CharID, TasksEnabled[i]);
    TaskQuery += buf;
    safe_delete_array(buf);
}
```

Comment: this would work in this instance, but this just an example. I'm trying to solve the larger issue. We have constructs where we have to check some 20 values fit a specific logic before we apply or don't apply the element.

Comment: ie, I'm looking for a way to append a joined constant string with separator, the *filtering* part is easy to do and should be something not to be consider.